# How to manage a printers queue through a asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, printing

I need to be able to print a bunch of documents in a sequence through my web app. How do i send these documents to the printer ? The documents are stored on a ftp server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to buy an activex plugin for IE, or write one yourself for firefox using XPI.